# Add Admin User in Drupal 6

Tags: 6, users

I have an old site built in Drupal 6 and I need to add a new admin user. I cannot give out user #1 and need a new one.

As far as roles go, I have authenticated and anonymous.

Is it as simply as adding a new role and granting full access or is there something a little easier I can do to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Admin role](https://drupal.org/project/adminrole) with this module you can add more **super users**.

> This module is a little helper to maintain an administrator role which
>   has all available permissions. By default, Drupal only has one super
>   user and this module helps improve this drastically.

Comment: I just created a role and granted full access because I didn't want to make any file changes in prod, but I've accepted your answer as I think it would work great!